# Innodb showing incorrect count(id)

Tags: mysql, innodb

have a innodb table with ~3G filesize (i use innodb_file_per_table = 1), just imported from dump and ~1.3G dump file. Have no idea how many recods exist here.

When i execute "select count(id) from $table" i see "27117291" (27,117,291 for readability).
When i execute "select count(id) from $table limit 100" i also see "27117291"

Why it is happening like this?
Is InnoDB *REALLY* better MyISAM?!

P.S. If i execute "select count(id) from $table where id=73010460;" i see "1".

Comment: What's the issue? Everything seems to be working correctly to me.

Comment: limit 100 says to take first 100 rows, not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select count(id) from $table
```

Returns one row with count in it. So your **limit** makes no difference.

(**[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html)**)

```
+-----------+
| COUNT(id) |
+-----------+
|  <count>  |
+-----------+
```

Comment: Yes. `LIMIT` limits the number of rows returned and does not set a maximum on the individual values that are returned.

Answer (score 4):

I'm no SQL expert, but my guess is that it is because count() only returns 1 row, thus limiting to 100 does nothing.

I'm guessing you would need to do something more like this to get the expected result:
select count((select id from x limit 100))

Answer (score 3):

limit doesn't work with that query. count query return 1 row and you are limiting 100 rows.
If your count query would return more than 100 rows it would be effective.

limit on that query doesn't limit counting, filters returning rows